# Show last three directories in the prompt

Tags: prompt, tcsh

I am trying to set prompt of the shell to show atleast last 3 directories.

I am using the following to show present working directory,

```
set prompt = " %~>" (Home directory will be replace with ~ in the prompt)
```

Right now, the prompt shows up like this

```
/root/MyDir1/MyDir2/MyDir3/MyDir4/MyDir5> _
```

I want it to be shown like this or so

```
MyDir3/MyDir4/MyDir5> _
```

Is there a way to set the prompt to show atleast the last 3 directories?